# Syntax of C++ templates with function type parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std-function

I'm used to seeing syntax like this for function pointers

```
int (*pointer_name) (float, char *);
void call_function (void (*)(int), int);
```

In some C++03 functional libraries I see types used this way:

```
abc::function<void(*)(int,float)> f;
```

In C++11's `std::function` I see the type given this way

```
std::function<void(int,float)> f;
```

There is a missing `(*)`. Why?

The C++03 `function<T>` has `T` being an identical type to the corresponding function pointer. It's easy to imagine the implementation.

`std::function` in C++11 is supported by core language enhancements. Have template argument types been extended to accomodate callability?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`std::function` (and its inspiration, `boost::function`) does not only store function pointers. It can also store function objects. In that sense, passing a *function signature* as a template parameter is similar to how a smart pointer usually take the type of the *pointee* as a template parameter, not a pointer type!

Contrast:

```
int* p; // indirection to an object of type int
std::unique_ptr<int> q; // indirection to an object of type int
```

with

```
typedef void signature_type(); // a function type

// indirection to something callable with signature_type as a signature
// i.e. f() has type void
// only work for freestanding functions however
signature_type* f;

// indirection to something callable with signature_type as a signature
// i.e. g() has type void
// not restricted to function pointers!
std::function<signature_type> g;
```

This is a useful convention.

Comment: This is so much nicer than the textbook pointer-to syntax! I wonder why we don't teach it this way normally...

Comment: @spraff: Probably because it's a relatively recent innovation, and most textbooks have very slow turnover. I still see people learning with Borland Turbo C++, which seems to have a great deal of trouble with this syntax.

Answer (score 10):

There is nothing magic here, the type

```
void(int,float)
```

is the type of a function without the names. It matches a function like `void g(int x, float y)`.

With templates you don't *have* to use function pointers, you can use function types as well.

Answer (score 9):

As with other elements, functions have a type, and you can use either the type or the pointer to the type in different contexts. The missing `(*)` you are expecting is just the *pointer-to* syntax.

```
int (*pointer_name) (float, char *);
typedef int my_function_type(float,char*);
my_function_type * pointer_name2;
```

The types of `pointer_name` and `pointer_name2` are the same: *pointer to a function that returns `int` and takes two arguments of types `float` and `char*`*. Note that this is exactly equivalent to other types like `int`, with the difference that you cannot declare a variable to be of type *function*, only *pointer to function*.

The interface of `std::function` (or `boost::function`) just takes the *signature* of the function. The type argument is not a *pointer to function* but rather the type of a function (like `my_function_type` in the code above)

Answer (score 3):

Function types aren't new in C++11 (see 8.3.5 in C++98).  IIRC, the improvement over what TR1 and boost provide for `function` are quite minor.