# Non-pointer typedef of member functions not allowed?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, function-pointers, typedef, pointer-to-member

After getting an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245235/syntax-of-c-templates-with-function-type-parameters) I discovered there are two valid ways to typedef a function pointer.

```
typedef void (Function) ();
typedef void (*PFunction) ();

void foo () {}

Function * p = foo;
PFunction  q = foo;
```

I now prefer `Function * p` to `PFunction q` but apparently this doesn't work for pointer-to-member functions. Consider this contrived example.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    typedef void (Base :: *Callback) ();
                        //^^^ remove this '*' and put it below (i.e. *cb)
    Callback cb;

    void go () {
        (this->*cb) ();
    }

    virtual void x () = 0;

    Base () {
        cb = &Base::x;
    }
};

struct D1 : public Base {
    void x () {
        std :: cout << "D1\n";
    }
};

struct D2 : public Base {
    void x () {
        std :: cout << "D2\n";
    }
};  

int main () {
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
    d1 .go ();
    d2 .go ();
}
```

But if I change it to the new preferred style: `typedef void (Base :: Callback) ()` and `Callback * cb`, I get a compiler error at the point of `typedef`

> extra qualification 'Base::' on member 'Callback'

[Demo for error](http://www.ideone.com/CoQmY).

Why is this not allowed? Is it simply an oversight or would it cause problems?

Comment: @Als now take the `*` away from typedef and you'll see what he means.

Comment: @Als, no it [doesn't compile](http://www.ideone.com/CoQmY).

Comment: To be precise: `typedef void Function();` defines an alias to the type *function taking not arguments and returning nothing*, note that there is no *pointer* in the type there... That typedef defines the signature of a function, not a pointer to a function with that signature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For non-member functions, a type such as `typedef void(Function)()` has several uses, but for member functions the only application is to declare a variable which holds a function pointer. Hence, other than a stylistic preference, there's no strict need to allow this syntax and it has been omitted from the standard.

#### Background

The `::` is a scope resolution operator, and the syntax `X::Y` is reserved for `static` member access if `X` is a class type. So `X::*Z` was another syntax invented to define *pointer-to-member*.

Forget *member-function* for a while, just think about *member-data*, and see this code:

```
struct X
{
   int a;
};

int X::*pa = &X::a; //pointer-to-member
X x = {100}; //a = 100
cout << (x.*pa) << endl;
```

It defines a *pointer-to-member-data*, and the `cout` uses it to print the value of `a` of object `x`, and it prints:

```
100
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/De2H1

Now think, if `X::pa` (as opposed to `X::*pa`) were allowed to do that, then you've written the above as:

```
int X::pa = X::a; //not &X::a
```

Seeing this syntax, how would you tell if `X::a` is a `static` member or non-static member? That is one reason why the Standard came up with *pointer-to-member* syntax, and uniformly applies it to *non-static member-data* as well as *non-static member-function*.

In fact, you **cannot** write `X::a`, you've to write `&X::a`. The syntax `X::a` would result in compilation error (see [this](http://www.ideone.com/FfGao)).

---

Now extend this argument of *member-data* to *member-function*. Suppose you've a typedef defined as:

```
typedef void fun();
```

then what do you think the following code does?

```
struct X
{
   fun a;
};
```

Well, it defines member `a` of type `fun` (which is function taking no argument, and returning void), and is equivalent to this:

```
struct X
{
   void a();
};
```

Surprised? Read on.

```
struct X
{
   fun a; //equivalent to this: void a();
};

void X::a() //yes, you can do this!
{
     cout << "haha" << endl;
}
```

We can use exactly the same syntax to refer to `a` which is now a member-function:

```
X x;
x.a(); //normal function call

void (X::*pa)() = &X::a; //pointer-to-member
(x.*pa)(); //using pointer-to-member
```

The similarity is the synatax on the right hand side : `&X::a`. Whether `a` refers to a member-function or member-data, the syntax is same.

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/Y80Mf

**Conclusion:**

As we know that we cannot write `X::a` on the RHS, no matter if `a` is a member-data or member-function. The only syntax which is allowed is `&X::f` which makes it necessary that the target type (on LHS) must be *pointer* as well, which in turn makes the syntax `void (X::*pa)()` absolutely necessary and fundamental, as it fits in with other syntax in the language.

Comment: Argument for `static` member access is quite **reasonable**. However, one thing is still to be addressed that, for member function pointer syntax we enclose it in `()` which will distinguish it with the `static` members.

Comment: @iammilind: I don't quite follow your comment... in the case of a member function, as in the case of a non-member function, you have to enclose with `()` which is funnily interpreted as enclosing *everything else other than what is inside the parenthesis* (niceties of the C declaration syntax) in the declaration, to distinguish the pointer to function from a function returning a pointer. I don't see where `static` members have anything to do with that set of parenthesis, or maybe I misunderstood your comment?

Comment: @David, according to Nawaz's answer, `::` is reserved for `static` member access (when used with `class` at LHS). So it's difficult for compiler to interpret that `::` is meant for class member function pointer declaration. I agree with that. ..... However, it can be argued that member function pointer can be still distinguished by extra `()` we put across. E.g. `typedef void (Base :: Callback) ();` ... in this case we can still say that `Callback` should be meant for class members and not `static` members; because it's enclosed in `()`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your final section on `int X::pa=X::a;` isn't relevant because it neither makes sense in and of itself nor has an analogy in member functions. You're talking about *objects* not *types*.

Comment: @iammilind: `void base::f()` is equivalent to `void (base::f)()` in the current standard, and what you propose would force a change in semantics there. Note that parenthesis are meant for *grouping* of elements, rather than changing semantics --admitedly, there are other cases where parenthesis can be used to change the meaning of the expression, as in `type t(( int() ));` where the extra set of parenthesis forces the parsing to be the creation of a local `t` by calling the constructor that takes an `int`, rather than declaration of a function that returns `type`...

Comment: @David, agree with you. In that case I don't have any argument with this answer (and already +1 this with my 1st comment).

Comment: @iammilind: You said, `However, it can be argued that member function pointer can be still distinguished by extra () we put across`.  That doesn't make any difference, because you can't write `X::f` on the RHS. The only syntax which is allowed is this : `&X::f` which makes it necessary that the target type must be *pointer* as well, which in turn makes the synax `void (X::*ptr)()` absolutely necessary and fundamental.

Comment: @spraff: And are you sure you know enough to judge answer of *your* question, the answer which you don't know in the first place? What is the point of allowing `void (X::fun)()` if you cannot use it? As the language doesn't allow `X::f` on the RHS, and the only syntax which allows is `&X::f` which is a *pointer*, which in turn makes it absolutely necessary that the *target* type must be a *pointer* of some form.

Comment: Here's the reason I don't accept your answer: from your conclusion " it necessary that the target type must be pointer as well". Yes. Fine. In the non-member case `PFunction x` is a pointer and `Function *x` is the same type of pointer. The question -- ***which you haven't answered*** -- is why the typedef style for `Function` does not work for analogous member functions whereas the style for `PFunction` carries over fine.

Comment: Funnily enough, your answer would be a very good answer, if only the question was different. :-)

Comment: @spraff: Because in case of non-member function, `Function` doesn't exist only for the syntax `Function *x`. It has other uses where PFunction **cannot** be used. One example is in my answer itself `struct X
{
   fun a;
};`. Trying using the typedef `void (*fun)()` here. It would not work. But in case of member function, there is no other use. So if the only is line : `MemFunction *x`, then why not make `MemFunction` is pointer itself, because `*` is a fundamental part of the syntax.

Comment: So you're saying it's not allowed purely because the alternative is sufficient for all use-cases?

Comment: @spraff: Exactly. I don't see any use of `MemFunctionType` without the `*`. If `MemFunctionType` is used along with `*`, then one thing pretty much clear that `MemFunctionType` **alone** is not completely meaningful in any circumstances. While in case of non-member function, `Function` has meaning on its own, and can be used where `PFunction` cannot be used!

Comment: Got there in the end. Thanks a lot, no, really, and I'm sorry this led to hostilities. I've taken the liberty of putting a summary at the top. Hope you don't find that arrogant too.

Answer (score 2):

To be precise the two typedef's in the case of the non-member pointers are not the same:

```
typedef void function();
typedef void (*fptr)();
```

The first defines `function` as a *function taking no arguments and returning `void`*, while the second defines `ftpr` as a *pointer to function taking no arguments and returning `void`*. The confusion probably arises as the function type will be implicitly converted to a pointer type in many contexts. But not all:

```
function f;            // declares void f();
struct test {
   function f;         // declares void test::f()
};
void g( function f );  // declares g( void (*f)() ): function decays to pointer to function in declaration
g( f );                // calls g( &f ): function decays to pointer to function
void f() {}            // definition of f
// function h = f;     // error: cannot assign functions
function *h = f;       // f decays to &f
```

Comment: Your `remove_ptr` doesn't work: http://ideone.com/mkifj I guess this means a pointer to type `void()` is not the same as the type `void(*)()` ?!

Comment: @spraff: You are right, the `remove_ptr` does not seem to be able to remove the pointer from a *pointer to member*. Now that I think about it, it would be technically impossible to do that, as the *pointer to member* is implemented not as a real pointer but as a complex structure that contains different information: for a member variable it will contain an offset from the beginning of the object, for a non-virtual function it will be a pointer to the actual function, and for a virtual function it has to contain an offset from the vtable... I will remove that part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's skip the "function" part for a second. In C++, we have the `int`, the `int*` and the `int Foo::*` types. That's a regular integer, pointer to integer, and a pointer to an integer member. There is no fourth type "integer member".

Exactly the same applies to functions: there's just no type "member function", even though there are function types, function pointer types, and member function pointer types.