# Understanding the template argument to std::function in C++11?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std, std-function

I am brushing up on some C++11 and am having a bit of a hard time understanding something.

`std::function` lets me pass any Callable type as a function object. I *know* what it does and how to use it.

```
void foo(int a, int b) {} 
std::function<void (int, int)> bar = foo;
...
```

`bar` is a callable object who'se target is `foo`, a function that takes two ints as parameters.

What I don't understand is exactly what `void (int, int)` means...

- I know it is the template parameter I am giving the compiler.
- I know that from it the compiler interprets that the callable type must take two ints and return void.

But, `void (int, int)` doesn't appear to "name a type".

- `void (*)(int, int)` is a pointer to a void returning function that takes two ints
- `void (Foo*::)(int, int)` is a pointer to Foo's void returning function that takes two ints

In fact the following toy snippet compiles fine.

```
class Foo {};
int main(int, char**)
{
    void (*)(int, int);
    void (Foo*::)(int, int);
}
```

But adding the expression `void (int, int)` causes a compile time error.

I did a little bit more digging around before posting my question.
The following code snippet compiles:

```
class Foo {};

template <typename T>
struct Bar
{
    typedef T type;
};

void a(int b, int c) {}

int main(int, char**)
{
    void (*)(int, int);
    void (Foo::*)(int, int);

    Bar<int (int, int)> bar;
}
```

But attempting to use `Bar::type` in any way produces another error: "invalidly declared function type".

---

TLDR:
What exactly does the expression `void (int, int)` mean **and** why is it a valid template parameter?

Thanks for any help you can send my way.

Comment: What compiler and options do you use for your "toy snippet"? As far as I can tell, it shouldn't compile..

Comment: I'm running g++ 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04LTS. Compiling with simple `g++ test.cpp -o test`, no flags or anything.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Syntax of C++ templates with function type parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7245235/)

Comment: *"no flags or anything"* That's not a good idea for many compilers. For g++, I'd suggest use `-std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra` to specify the version of the Standard it shall follow, and warn about non-standard extensions it accepts.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the second reply, it was exactly the answer I was looking for. I looked around for it and really didn't run into it. It's a **function signature**. Function signatures can be passed as template parameters -- I didn't know... Hey thanks again.

Comment: So you agree that `void (*)(int, int)` names a type, and that it's a pointer to something. How would you name the type of the thing it points to?

Comment: @JDR Someone very pedantic might point out that `void(int,int)` is not actually a *function signature*, since the signature of (non-template) functions does not contain the return type ;) (That makes me very pedantic, I guess.) It can be called a *function type*, since it's the type of a function. You can even declare, but not define a *function* using a *function type*. E.g. `using FT = void(int); FT myFunc; void myFunc(int) {}`

Answer (score 1):

Not all types have values.  `void` is the most well know example.

`void(int,int)` is just a type that is the type of no values.  And it is useful, so it is used.

The type can be used outside of template arguments in a few spots.  For example, it can be used to declare a method or a function, or a pointer to the type can be used as a function pointer, or a reference as a function reference.

Answer (score 0):

dyp pointed me to the correct [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7245235/). This was a duplicate question.

void (int, int) represents a "function signature" and function signatures can be passed as template parameters.

Comment: Specifically, `void(int,int)` is not only a signature, but in _certain_ contexts, is also a type. Namely, the type of the "object" that `void(*)(int,int)` points to.   functions aren't truly objects in C++ though, for the same reason that `void(int,int)` isn't a real type: the type has no size.

Comment: @TBohne `void` also has no size, and so does `int[]`. The C++ Standard calls all of them types, though. `void(int,int)` isn't a signature either, using the terminology of the Standard.